# Multicols: numbered columns

Tags: multicol

I simply would like to have a column number like a page number under each column.

```
\documentclass[paper=A3, landscape]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{4}
  \blinddocument{}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

... instead of the pagenumber. There will be no references (`\pageref`) to the columnnumber.

Comment: Is this to be in addition to the page number, or instead of? If there is to be a page number: at top or bottom of page?

Comment: Or are you assuming (like this example) the columns will end before the page does?

Comment: Should the column numbers be sequential? That is, 1-4 on page 1, 5-8 on page 2, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a single page:

```
\documentclass[paper=A3, landscape]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{4}
  \blinddocument{}
\end{multicols}
\columnwidth=\dimexpr \textwidth-3\columnsep\relax% recompute
\columnwidth=0.25\columnwidth
\noindent
\makebox[\columnwidth]{1}\hspace{\columnsep}%
\makebox[\columnwidth]{2}\hspace{\columnsep}%
\makebox[\columnwidth]{3}\hspace{\columnsep}%
\makebox[\columnwidth]{4}\par
\end{document}
```

For every page:

```
\documentclass[paper=A3, landscape]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{everypage}

\newcounter{column}

\AddEverypageHook{\ifdim\columnwidth<\textwidth
  \ifodd\value{page}\rlap{\hspace{\oddsidemargin}%
      \raisebox{\dimexpr-\topmargin-\headheight-\headsep-\textheight-0.5\footskip}[0pt][0pt]%
      {\makebox[\columnwidth]{\stepcounter{column}\thecolumn}\hspace{\columnsep}%
       \makebox[\columnwidth]{\stepcounter{column}\thecolumn}\hspace{\columnsep}%
       \makebox[\columnwidth]{\stepcounter{column}\thecolumn}\hspace{\columnsep}%
       \makebox[\columnwidth]{\stepcounter{column}\thecolumn}}}%
  \else\rlap{\hspace{\evensidemargin}%
      \raisebox{\dimexpr-\topmargin-\headheight-\headsep-\textheight-0.5\footskip}[0pt][0pt]%
      {\makebox[\columnwidth]{\stepcounter{column}\thecolumn}\hspace{\columnsep}%
       \makebox[\columnwidth]{\stepcounter{column}\thecolumn}\hspace{\columnsep}%
       \makebox[\columnwidth]{\stepcounter{column}\thecolumn}\hspace{\columnsep}%
       \makebox[\columnwidth]{\stepcounter{column}\thecolumn}}}%
  \fi%
\fi}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{4}
  \blinddocument{} \blindtext
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```