# Numbered columns – suppress column number on first page

Tags: page-numbering, everypage

I would like to hide the column number on the first column (cover page).

I have used the following code from: 
[Stack Exchange Answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/329274/124034)

```
\documentclass[paper=A3, landscape]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{everypage}

\newcounter{column}

\AddEverypageHook{\ifdim\columnwidth<\textwidth
  \ifodd\value{page}\rlap{\hspace{\oddsidemargin}%
      \raisebox{\dimexpr-\topmargin-\headheight-\headsep-\textheight-    0.5\footskip}[0pt][0pt]%
  {\makebox[\columnwidth]{\stepcounter{column}\thecolumn}\hspace{\columnsep}%
   \makebox[\columnwidth]{\stepcounter{column}\thecolumn}\hspace{\columnsep}%
   \makebox[\columnwidth]{\stepcounter{column}\thecolumn}\hspace{\columnsep}%
   \makebox[\columnwidth]{\stepcounter{column}\thecolumn}}}%
\else\rlap{\hspace{\evensidemargin}%
  \raisebox{\dimexpr-\topmargin-\headheight-\headsep-\textheight-0.5\footskip}[0pt][0pt]%
  {\makebox[\columnwidth]{\stepcounter{column}\thecolumn}\hspace{\columnsep}%
   \makebox[\columnwidth]{\stepcounter{column}\thecolumn}\hspace{\columnsep}%
   \makebox[\columnwidth]{\stepcounter{column}\thecolumn}\hspace{\columnsep}%
   \makebox[\columnwidth]{\stepcounter{column}\thecolumn}}}%
\fi%
\fi}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{4}
  \blinddocument{} \blindtext
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

I have tried it with

```
\thispagestyle{empty}
```

but it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `\thecolumn`, you can use a command that will only produce a result if the `column` counter is different from 1. Here I named it `\tehcolumn`, based on a common misspelling (yes, that's a joke):

```
\documentclass[paper=A3, landscape]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{everypage}

\newcounter{column}

\newcommand\tehcolumn{\ifnum\value{column}=1 \else\thecolumn\fi}

\AddEverypageHook{\ifdim\columnwidth<\textwidth
  \ifodd\value{page}\rlap{\hspace{\oddsidemargin}%
      \raisebox{\dimexpr-\topmargin-\headheight-\headsep-\textheight-    0.5\footskip}[0pt][0pt]%
  {\makebox[\columnwidth]{\stepcounter{column}\tehcolumn}\hspace{\columnsep}%
   \makebox[\columnwidth]{\stepcounter{column}\tehcolumn}\hspace{\columnsep}%
   \makebox[\columnwidth]{\stepcounter{column}\tehcolumn}\hspace{\columnsep}%
   \makebox[\columnwidth]{\stepcounter{column}\tehcolumn}}}%
\else\rlap{\hspace{\evensidemargin}%
  \raisebox{\dimexpr-\topmargin-\headheight-\headsep-\textheight-0.5\footskip}[0pt][0pt]%
  {\makebox[\columnwidth]{\stepcounter{column}\tehcolumn}\hspace{\columnsep}%
   \makebox[\columnwidth]{\stepcounter{column}\tehcolumn}\hspace{\columnsep}%
   \makebox[\columnwidth]{\stepcounter{column}\tehcolumn}\hspace{\columnsep}%
   \makebox[\columnwidth]{\stepcounter{column}\tehcolumn}}}%
\fi%
\fi}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{4}
  \blinddocument{} \blindtext
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```